# Need to access associative array data created inside a class by json_decode from outside the class

Tags: php, arrays, class, json

I've been using procedural php for a long time but am still learning OOP.  I was able to find a bit of code online that is in the form of a class and I am able to call a new instance of the class and use var_dump on a string to have it print JSON data to a web page.  I can look at the results of the var_dump and see that it's returning exactly what I want.  I'm then able to use json_decode on the same string to turn it into and associative array and then I can echo the values from within the class.  The problem is, I need to use the array values in more code - it's great that I can confirm it by printing it to a web page but I need to use it... but I'm getting errors that state the array is undefined once I try to access it outside of the class.

I'm using this line to convert the data into an array:

```
$response_array = json_decode($body, true);
```

I've already confirmed that this works within the class by using this code to print some of the data:

```
echo $response_array['amount'];
```

and it works - I see it on the web page.

I've been using this code to create the new instance of the class:

```
$fdata = new FData();
$fdata->request($order_total, $cc_exp, $cc_number, $cc_name, $order_id, $customer_id);
```

(the function named 'request' is defined as a public function inside the class)

After that, I want to grab the $response_array so that I can store the returned data into a transactions table, i.e something like this:

```
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, "CALL add_transaction($order_id, $response_array['transaction_type'], $response_array['amount'], $response_array['exact_resp_code'], $response_array['exact_message'], $response_array['bank_resp_code'], $response_array['bank_message'], $response_array['sequence_no'], $response_array['retrieval_ref_no'], $response_array['transaction_tag'], $response_array['authorization_num'])");
```

but I keep getting an error saying that the array values are undefined.

Things I have already tried (and which failed) include:

1. Defining the variables as public inside the class, setting their value in the class, and then calling them outside the class...

   ```
   public $amount = $response_array['amount'];
   ```

   then using $amount in my procedure CALL --- I still get the error saying that $amount is undefined.
2. Using 'return', as in

   ```
   return $response_array;
   ```

   and still the error saying the values are undefined.
3. I tried embedding the entire rest of my code within the class, just copy/paste it in right after the json_decode... but for some reason it can't seem to then make the database calls and other things it needs to do.

I've been reading about `__construct` but I'm not sure if it applies or how to use it in this case...

I want to stress that I AM able to see the results I want when I use var_dump and echo from within the class.. I need to access the array created by json_decode OUTSIDE of the instance of the class.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You're going to have to show some more code instead of little, unrelated snippets. For point #2, when you say you use `return $response_array`, is that within `FData::request`? Are you assigning that return value to a variable?

Comment: FYI `__construct` is the name given to a class' constructor method. It is what executes when you call `new ClassName()`. See http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: How is `$response_array` getting to `$fdata`? Are you assign the array and accessing it by using `$this->response_array`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `FData::request` method ends with something like this...

```
$response_array = json_decode($body, true);
return $response_array;
```

and you call it like this...

```
$response_array = $fdata->request(...);
```

You should then be able to use `$response_array` in the calling scope.

Extra note; you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.prepare.php) with [parameter binding](http://php.net/manual/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) instead of injecting values directly into your SQL statements.

Comment: Thank you Phil.  I didn't know I could use = and -> in the same line; for some reason I thought that had to be done as two lines/steps.  Very helpful and very much appreciated.

Comment: @EricBrockway PHP uses *explicit* return statements. This differs to languages like Ruby that use *implicit* returns